# Link MongoDB collections

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am trying to convert the Meteor tutorial app, simple-todo, into a forum. I have a list that populates with Topics with a delete button and a radio button.

What I want to do, is when a Topic's radio button is selected, display all the comments associated with it. I am trying to accomplish this by putting the topicId(originally taskId), used in the tutorial, in a new Collection called Comments. I then query the Comments for that topicId.the comments are mostly copied and pasted topics, so the attributes and functionality of the two is mostly the same.

I, right now, don't know how to get to the topicId from my `Template.body.events`. If you can help me tie these two DB's together, that would be very helpful.

HTML:

```
<head>
  <title>Forum</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="login">
    {{> loginButtons}}
  </div>

<nav class="mainMenu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="forum.html">Forum</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="container">
    <header>
        <h1>Forum</h1>
    <h2>Post a topic</h2>

  {{#if currentUser}}
     <form class="new-topic">
        <input type="topicalContent" name="topicalContent" placeholder="Type to add new topics" />
     </form>
  {{/if}}
</header>

  <table>
    <td class="topicsCol">
      <h3>Topics</h3>

      <ul class="topicsList">
        {{#each topics}}
        {{> topic}}
        {{/each}}
      </ul>
    </td>
    <td class="commentsCol">
      <h3>Comments</h3>

      <ul class="commentsList">
        {{#each comments}}
        {{> comment}}
        {{/each}}
      </ul>

      <input type="commentContent" name="commentContent" placeholder="Type to Comment" />
    </td>
  </table>
</div>
</body>

<template name="topic">
<li class="{{#if selected}}select{{/if}}">
<button class="delete">&times;</button>

<span class="topicalContent">{{topicalContent}} -<strong>{{username}}</strong></span>

<input type="radio" name="curTopic" value="{{curTopic}}" />
</li>
</template>

<template name="commentsList">
  <li class="comment">
    <button class="delete">&times;</button>
    <span class="responseContent">
      <strong>
        <!-- {{#if username === owner}}
          <style="color:red;">OP
        {{else}}-->
          {{username}}
        <!--{{/if}}-->
      </strong>: {{responseContent}}</span>
  </li>
</template>
```

JavaScript:

```
Topics = new Mongo.Collection("topics");
Comments = new Mongo.Collection("comments");


if(Meteor.isServer){
  Meteor.publish("topics", function(){
    return Topics.find({
      $or: [
        { owner: this.userId }
      ]
    });
  });

  Meteor.publish("comments", function(){
    return Comments.find({
      $or: [
        { parent: topicId },
        { owner: this.userId }
      ]
    });
  });
}


if (Meteor.isClient) {
  // This code only runs on the client
  Meteor.subscribe("topics");
  Meteor.subscribe("comments");

  Template.body.helpers({
      topics: function() {
      return Topics.find({}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}});
    },

    comments: function () {
      return Comments.find({parent: {parent: topicId}}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}});
    }
  });

  Template.body.events({
      "submit .new-topic": function (event) {
          //Prevent default browser form submit
          event.preventDefault();

          //Get value from form element
          var topicalContent = event.target.topicalContent.value;

      if (topicalContent == "") {
        throw new Meteor.Error("Empty Input");
      }

          //Insert a topic into the collection
          Meteor.call("addTopic", topicalContent);

          //Clear form
          event.target.topicalContent.value = "";
    },

    "submit .commentContent": function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      var commentContent = event.target.commentContent.value;

      Meteor.call("addComment", this.topicId);

      event.target.commentContent.value= "";
    }
  });


  Template.topic.helpers({
    isOwner: function(){
      return this.owner === Meteor.userId();
    }
  });

  Template.topic.events({
      "click .curTopic": function() {
          //Show Comments of selected radio button
      Meteor.call("showComments", this._id);
    },

    "click .delete":function () {
      Meteor.call("deleteTopic", this._id);
    }
  });

  Template.comment.helpers({
    isOwner: function(){
       return this.owner === Meteor.userId();
    }
  });
  Template.comment.events({
    "click .delete":function () {
      Meteor.call("deleteComment", this._id);
    }
  });

  Accounts.ui.config({
    passwordSignupFields: "USERNAME_ONLY"
  });
}

Meteor.methods({
  addTopic:function(topicalContent){
     if (!Meteor.userId()) {
       throw new Meteor.Error("not-authorized");
     }

     Topics.insert({
       topicalContent,
       createdAt: new Date(),
       owner: Meteor.userId(),
       username: Meteor.user().username
     });
  },
  deleteTopic:function(topicId) {
    var topic = Topics.findOne(topicId);
    if (topic.owner !== Meteor.userId()) {
      throw new Meteor.Error("not-authorized");
    }
    else {
      Topics.remove(topicId);
    }
  },

  showComments:function (topicId) {
    Comments.find({"parent":topicId});
  },
  addComment:function(commentContent, topicId){
     if (!Meteor.userId()) {
       throw new Meteor.Error("not-authorized");
     }

     Comments.insert({
       commentContent,
       createdAt: new Date(),
       owner: Meteor.userId(),
       username: Meteor.user().username,
       parent: topicId
     });
  },
  deleteComment:function(commentId) {
    var comment = Comments.findOne(commentId);
    if (comment.owner !== Meteor.userId()) {
      throw new Meteor.Error("not-authorized");
    }
    else {
      Comments.remove(commentId);
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

*One way* (and there are many) is to use a session variable to track the current topic. In your `topic` event handler:

```
Template.topic.events({
  "click .curTopic": function() {
    Session.set('topicId',this._id); // set the Session variable
    Meteor.call("showComments", this._id);
});
```

Now everywhere else you're looking for the current `topicId` you can just use `Session.get('topicId');`

Comment: But by the way, there are numerous other issues in your code beyond just sharing the state of the radio buttons however. How you're publishing `Comments` for example. Your publish function is going to need the `topicId` and you don't need that method call at all.